# having problems to execute a PHP code with simple mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a query with a WHERE clause but it looks like the id I retrieve needs to be perhaps converted from an array into something else. I am new to PHP so I am struggling a little:

```
...some previous query here
$sharepoint_id = $data[0];
//returns Array([ID] => a5f415a7-3d4f-11e5-b52f-b82a72d52c35)   

qry = mysql_query("SELECT HostName FROM MSSWireList WHERE id=".$sharepoint_id);     
    $data = array();
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $data[] = array(
                    "ID"          => $rows['ID'],
                    "Record"      => $rows['Record'],                                
                    "HostName"    => $rows['HostName']
                    );
    }
    return json_encode($data);
```

also tried     $sharepoint_id = $data[0]->ID;
Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?done

Comment: What's wrong with JOIN?

Comment: I really must concentrate on cultivating the habit of asking, "***What does the error message say?***"

Comment: Your 'qry' does not have a dollar sign in front of it.

Comment: @FintanCreaven I noticed that too [and asked them about it in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966745/having-problems-to-execute-a-php-code-with-simple-mysql-query/33966767?noredirect=1#comment55691261_33966761) under my (edited) answer, but haven't gotten feedback from it, or any other comment for that matter. I'll add it in my answer, just... in... case.

Comment: He/ she needs to make the syntax changes. Add in error catching code suggested in the answer given and confirm that we are all at the same stage. I imagine once all changes are made it will work.

Comment: sorry guys, the code is okay it was just a typo here. The suggestion from Darwin worked well. Yes I am doing maintenance in a crap code where they don't use mysqli or PDO and I am new to PHP so you know how it goes...frustration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't take you to task for using the old mysql driver instead of mysqli or PDO, or for not using a prepared statement - I'll leave that for others to do - but

```
"...WHERE id = '" . $sharepoint_id['ID'] . "'"
```

should do the job.

Comment: I actually thought you were right on this one. We both got a nice downvote. Not my downvote btw. Seems like whoever downvoted us, doesn't want to share their popcorn with us ;-)

Comment: 'S okay - I have a little extra popcorn to share.

Comment: what I don't get is that they show us `returns Array([ID] => a5f415a7-3d4f-11e5-b52f-b82a72d52c35)` - no idea why either of our answers would fail him. Oh well, I might end up deleting my answer and go to the store to get me a soda for that popcorn ;-) after I finish my sandwich.

Comment: Who knows. Could be anyone. Could even be Groucho Marx ;-) I made an edit to my answer, could be an added contribution to their query failing.

Answer (score 1):

> *"returns Array([ID] => a5f415a7-3d4f-11e5-b52f-b82a72d52c35)"*

That's a string and not an integer. The variable in your `WHERE` clause needs to be quoted.

```
WHERE id='".$sharepoint_id."' ");
```

Checking for errors would have signaled the syntax error.

Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

- Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

Edit:

You only selected the `HostName` column from your query and not the other two, `ID` and `Record`.

However, when going over a loop, row names are case-sensitive.

So, if your row's case is `id` as opposed to `ID`, then that will matter in your loop.

- `$rows['ID']` and `$rows['id']` are two different animals.

Sidenote:

Pulled from a comment I asked already:

`qry = mysql_query` if that your real code, it's missing a `$` for `qry`.

And if so, error reporting would have thrown you an undefined constant qry notice.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Array to string conversion in Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @Max what method are you using to connect with, the same as your query? such as `mysql_`? or are you using `mysqli_` or PDO?

Comment: @Max See Darwin's answer. Seems like he may be correct. Someone agreed with him.

Comment: @Max curious though. `qry = mysql_query` is that your real code? seems it's missing a `$` for `qry`

Comment: well sir it took me awhile to get this thing to work. The syntax is weird but it worked now. And I didn't downvote anyone.